# Using parallel streams for finding similar strings in an array?

Tags: java, java-stream

Let's say I have a large array of unique strings and I want **to find all pairs which are at least 50% similar**.

A straightforward implementation:

```
final String[] strings = {"abc", "dsfdsf", "foo", "baaa", ...};

final Collection<Pair<String, String>> matches = new ArrayList<>();

for (final String s1 : strings) {
    for (final String s2 : strings) {
        if (calculateSimilarity(s1, s2) >= 0.5) {
            matches.add(new Pair(s1, s2));
        }
    }
}
```

Now, let's make it multithreaded by using parallel stream:

```
for (final String s1 : strings) {
    Arrays.stream(strings).parallel()
        .filter(s2 -> calculateSimilarity(s1, s2) >= 0.5)
        .collect(toList())
        .stream()
        .forEach(s2 -> matches.add(new Pair(s1, s2)));
}
```

Each subsequent **s1** string is compared (in parallel) with all **s2** strings. All strings matching **s1** are collected into a single list, and then they are added sequentially to **matches** (because **ArrayList** is not thread-safe).

This already works much faster than the sequential version. However, I want to introduce an improvement: avoid comparing the same two strings twice, because always **calculateSimilarity("aaa", "bbb") == calculateSimilarity("bbb", "aaa")**. I would also like to avoid comparing each string against itself.

So, back to the original algorithm:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < strings.length; j++) {  // <--- sic! NOT int j = 0
            if (calculateSimilarity(strings[i], strings[j]) >= 0.5) {
                matches.add(new Pair(strings[i], strings[j]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, my question is: **how to introduce this improvement to the parallel stream version?**

Should I use **.skip()** somehow?

Comment: Well, you could try `Arrays.stream(strings, i+1, strings.length)` and use a traditional for loop as the outer loop, i.e. `for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) { String s1 = strings[i]; Arrays.stream(strings, i+1, strings.length)... }`. However, I'd still try to think about other algorithms that aren't basically O(n^2) - is similiarity just based on the number of equal chars in the same place?

Comment: ..inside `calculateSimilarity` ..utilizing thread safe data structures .. (!?;)

Comment: CopyOnWriteArrayList is threadsafe.

Comment: What you are asking is really similar to dynamic programming memoization:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

Comment: I think you can replace `.collect(toList()).stream().forEach(...)` with `.forEachOrdered(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers, they were very informative!

In the end, I went with the following implementation:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    final String s1 = strings[i];
    Arrays.stream(strings)
        .skip(i + 1)
        .parallel()
        .filter(s2 -> calculateSimilarity(s1, s2) >= 0.5)
        .collect(toList())
        .stream()
        .forEach(s2 -> matches.add(new Pair(s1, s2)));
}
```

It is slightly slower than:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    final String s1 = strings[i];
    Arrays.stream(strings, i + 1 /* startInclusive */, strings.length /* endExclusive */)
        .parallel()
        .filter(s2 -> calculateSimilarity(s1, s2) >= 0.5)
        .collect(toList())
        .stream()
        .forEach(s2 -> matches.add(new Pair(s1, s2)));
}
```

...but `skip()` works with any collection, not only with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is based on the approach of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73894488/139985), but it uses Java 8 streams and adds some parallelism.

```
int len = strings.length;
List<Pair<String, String>> result = 
      LongStream.range(0, (long)(len) * len))
                .parallel()
                .filter(l -> (l / len > l % len) && 
                             calculateSimilarity(strings[l / len], 
                                                 strings[l % len]) > 0.5)
                .map(l -> new Pair<>(strings[l / len], strings[l % len])
                .collect(toList());
```

The approach used is to use `l` to iterate the positions of an imaginary `len` x `len` matrix flattened into 1-D.  The `(l / len)` and `(l % len)` map the 1-D coordinates to 2-D, and then the `(l / len > l % len)` test checks that we are above the diagonal of the 2-D matrix.

I try to avoid creating any intermediate structures (e.g. temporary arrays or a de-duping `HashSet`) and any `Pair` objects that would be discarded.

Notes:

1. If we could constrain the length of `strings` to be less than 2^16, we could use an `IntStream` and `int` calculations.
2. If there are duplicates in the input `strings` array, there will be duplicates in the list of `Pair` objects.
3. This is still going to be `O(N^2)` where `N` is `strings.length`.

Comment: …and if you want maximum performance, skip the creation of a `Pair<String,String>` and collecting into a `List` part and just use `toArray()`, to get a a `long[]`. Since the original array still exists, extracting the actual strings can be postponed to the time when they are needed, e.g. for printing them. I don’t think that using `int` instead of `long` has a noticeable effect on today’s machines.

Comment: 1) True.  But that changes the problem. 2) `int` vs `long` you are probably right, based on a quick look at this: https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf

Answer (score 0):

if you use an indexed for loop you can look at the indexes above current index only to reduce number of comparisons and skip itself

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
  String s1 = strings[i];
  for (int j = i + 1; j < strings.length; j++) { //<--- inner loop only looks at "new comparisons" due to i+1
    String s2 = strings[j];
    if (calculateSimilarity(s1, s2)) {
        matches.add(new Pair(s1, s2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of knowing that similarity is idempotent, so you only need to compare from the string next position in array onwards.

Also, if possible, you can take advantage of stream parallel execution to process large arrays.

The following is an example of how you can achieve it.

```
final double ACCEPTED_SIMILARITY_INDEX = 0.75;
String[] strings = {"A", "B", "C", "AA", "BB"};

final Set<Set<ImmutablePair<String, String>>> collect = IntStream
    .range(0, strings.length)
    .parallel()
    .mapToObj(index -> new ImmutablePair<>(strings[index], index + 1))
    .map(immutablePair -> Arrays.stream(strings, immutablePair.right, strings.length).parallel()
        .filter(stringToCompare -> new JaccardDistance().apply(stringToCompare, immutablePair.left) > ACCEPTED_SIMILARITY_INDEX)
        .map(similarString -> new ImmutablePair<>(immutablePair.left, similarString)).collect(Collectors.toSet())).filter(workingSet -> !workingSet.isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store the input strings in a `List` instead of an array, the adjusted version of your implementation that combines a `for` loop with a `Stream` is

```java
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("abc", "dsfdsf", "foo", "baaa", ...);

for (int index = 0; index < strings.length - 1; index++) {
    final String s1 = strings.get(index);
    strings.subList(index+1, strings.length)
        .stream()
        .parallel()
        .filter(s2 -> calculateSimilarity(s1, s2) >= 0.5)
        .collect(toList())
        .stream()
        .forEach(s2 -> matches.add(new Pair(s1, s2)));
}
```